# How to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

How to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (Javascript)?

Comment: Please add some more info where the data is coming from. Most often, the browser can do the conversion

Comment: It is read from id3 tags by SoundManager.

Comment: @Pekka: I believe this question is a follow-up to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451489/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to since javascript strings are unicode. I assume you want to read ISO-8859-1 sources and write UTF-8 output. But in this case it depends on what you want to read and what you want to write. So please be more specific.